# Moving over a rectangle in pygame

Tags: python, algorithm, pygame

For example, I have a rows of cheese like the image below and there is an animal to eat it. Problem is once I eat the cheese, the animal has to move over and the cheese has to be removed. I am not sure how to do this. Need some guidance on this.

[image]

My Pet class looks like this:

```
class Pet(object):
    active = None

    def __init__(self):
        self.rect = pygame.Rect(32, 32, 16, 16)

    def move(self, dx, dy):

        if Pet.active and isinstance(self, Pet.active):
            if dx != 0:
                self.move_single_axis(dx, 0)
            if dy != 0:
                self.move_single_axis(0, dy)

    def move_single_axis(self, dx, dy):

        # Move the rect
        self.rect.x += dx
        self.rect.y += dy

        # If you collide with a wall, move out based on velocity
        for wall in walls:
            if self.rect.colliderect(wall.rect):
                if dx > 0: # Moving right; Hit the left side of the wall
                    self.rect.right = wall.rect.left
                if dx < 0: # Moving left; Hit the right side of the wall
                    self.rect.left = wall.rect.right
                if dy > 0: # Moving down; Hit the top side of the wall
                    self.rect.bottom = wall.rect.top
                if dy < 0: # Moving up; Hit the bottom side of the wall
                    self.rect.top = wall.rect.bottom
        for circle in circles:
            if mouse.rect.contains(circle.circle):
                #stuck here
```

My cheese is drawn this way:

```
level = [
"WWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWW",
"WWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWW",
"WWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWW",
"WWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWW",
"WWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWW",
"WWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWW",
"WWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWW",
"WWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWW",
"WWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWW",
"WWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWW",
"WWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWW",
"WWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWW",
"WWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWW",
]

# Parse the level string above. W = wall, E = exit
x = y = 0
for row in level:
    for col in row:
        if col == "W":
            Wall((x, y))
        x += 16
    y += 16
    x = 0

for wall in walls:
        pygame.draw.rect(screen, Yellow, circle.circle)
```

I would appreciate if anyone could help out in doing this part...

Comment: My pygame is botched right now, so I can't prototype. But the idea is simple: your level contains not only your chees, but your pet as well. So make it a list of lists where each element is either "W", "E", " " (empty) or "P" (pet). Then on each movement of the player, you check if the movement is allowed (no leaving the world, no walls), replace the current position of the P with a " ", and place the P over the next position. Then, redraw your whole level.

Comment: How do you replace W with P? That's where I am confused. If necessary I can share my code with u..

Comment: `level[col][row] = 'P'`

Comment: Tim's right, but for that to work, you have to convert your level-definition to a list of list, as I also mentioned. E.g. converted_level = [list(row) for row in level] will do the trick.

Comment: @TimCastelijns I understand the part of changing the value to 'P'. The part I am confused is I am using walls to draw on the screen and when it collides with a pet, how to change the original level?

Comment: Shared my whole code: https://www.dropbox.com/s/omqj5121ev43mxc/Test.py?dl=0

Comment: @deets a string can be treated as a list of chars

Comment: @TimCastelijns For reading - yes. For assignment this would mean mutable strings. Last time I checked, Python strings were immutable. Which is what the OP showed above in his snippet. Thus my suggestion for a list of list. Alternatively an array of bytes could be used, but I rarely see a use for them, unless you are severely memory-constrained.

Comment: @deets ah you're right that slipped my mind for a minute

Comment: Can you guys show an example? will hugely appreciate..

Comment: @deets how do you do this statement=> "replace the current position of the P with a " " "? how do you find the current position? how to get the current row and column?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at this. I suggest though you work through a Python tutorial to understand data-structures better.

```
  from itertools import product

  level_definition = """
  WWWWWWW
  WCCCCCW
  WCCCCCW
  WCCPCCW
  WWWWWWW
  """

  class Level(object):

      def __init__(self, definition):
          self._data = [
              list(line.strip()) for line in
              definition.split("\n") if line.strip()
              ]

          self.height = len(self._data)
          self.width = len(self._data[0])
          for x, y in product(xrange(self.width), xrange(self.height)):
              if self[x][y] == "P":
                  self[x][y] = " "
                  self.initial_player_position = (x, y)
                  break


      def __getitem__(self, column):
          level = self
          class ColAccessor(object):

              def __getitem__(self, row):
                  return level._data[row][column]


              def __setitem__(self, row, value):
                  level._data[row][column] = value


          return ColAccessor()


      def __str__(self):
          return "\n".join("".join(row) for row in self._data)

  class Player(object):

      def __init__(self, level):
          self._pos = level.initial_player_position
          self._level = level

      def move(self, xoffset=0, yoffset=0):
          newx, newy = self._pos[0] + xoffset, self._pos[1] + yoffset
          try:
              next_thing = self._level[newx][newy]
          except IndexError:
              # you moved outside the bounds, impossible
              # so pretend we hit a wall
              return "W", self._pos
          if next_thing == "W":
              # you hit a wall
              return next_thing, self._pos
          self._level[newx][newy] = " "
          self._pos = newx, newy 
          return next_thing, self._pos


  if __name__ == "__main__":
      level = Level(level_definition)
      assert level[3][3] == " "
      player = Player(level)
      for _ in xrange(3):
          print player.move(-1)

      print str(level)
```

Comment: I need your help. I have converted my level string to a list of lists. when I try to eat the cheese, I am still not able to go over the cheese. cheese still remains.